# How to copy Digital Ocean app folder to local machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal, digital-ocean

I'd like to copy the contents of my app folder from my Digital Ocean droplet to my local machine, because I've accidentally removed the app from my local machine and need it back.

I've tried the following, as an example,

```
scp -r root@104.232.321.32:/PATH-TO-APP
```

Which gave me the following,

```
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

How do I copy the app to my local machine? I need to set a destination for scp to work, what destination can i set so it copys to local machine, /User/sites directory?

Comment: Any local path where you can write will work... `scp -r root@104.232.321.32:/PATH-TO-APP  /Users/Chris/local-path`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
scp -r root@104.232.321.32:/PATH-TO-APP .
```

This should copy it to the current directory. You could also do:

```
scp -r root@104.232.321.32:/PATH-TO-APP ~/project
```

To copy it to a specific folder.

Two tangential observations, by the way:

1. Stop using your DigitalOcean droplet as root. You should make your own user account on the Droplet and set up SSH authentication.
2. You should be using Git to keep the remote copy of your project and your local copy in sync, not `scp` (granted, this may be a strange case, but just making sure you're aware).

Comment: You're probably looking for `~/apps`, not `/apps`. `~/apps` is an alias for `$HOME/apps`, which means "the `apps` directory in my home directory". `/apps` means "the `apps` directory at the root of my filesystem".

Comment: Thanks got it! seems to be taking a LONG time though to copy, does -r mea n that it repeats by any chance? Or does it typically take long, if it's a larger app

Comment: If you look at the man pages for `scp` (run `man scp` or [go here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html)), you can see that the `-r` flag means to recursively copy sub-folders. `-r` can basically be treated as the "folder flag" for most bash programs: `rm -r` to delete a folder, `cp -r` to copy a folder, etc. You can omit the flag when copying a single file or list of files.

Comment: Cheers @StevenPetryk, got it. Will it ever end though by it self? Or do I have to end it manually? When I hear recursive, I think of repetition. Some definitions may say reputation to succession... So will it stop when it's done copying? Or continue copying indefinitely?

Comment: It'll stop when it's done. In any context, if recursion leads to infinite runtime, that's a bug. SCP is particularly slow because it has to negotiate the transfer of each individual file when downloading. I'd recommend using `tar` to ZIP (sort of) your project folder into a `.tar.gz` and then just transfer that one huge file instead of thousands of tiny files.

Comment: Example (untested): https://gist.github.com/stevenpetryk/e9b7e170bc993b7f9bfbfcf0bfec3bc7

Comment: Thanks! makes sense, one last thing - will others be able to use the droplet while I'm doing this copying? Will they know that Im copying, because I don't want to hinder their performance..

Comment: If there are other users of the droplet, then maybe, but I doubt it. DigitalOcean has a pretty widely distributed cluster that can likely handle many concurrent downloads per Droplet, since your Droplet isn't running on a real, singular computer. I'm no ops expert though.